# How to merge specific commit id from different branch in same repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, cherry-pick, git-add

I had two branches master & trunk.

I have created one more branch in local using `git checkout -b new_branch origin/master` to take the master code in that branch.

I have added committed some changes in this new branch & pushed as:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "my custom message"
git push origin new_branch
```

Now i have to merge only this commit id changes(In branch new_branch) in my trunk branch.

I know about `git cherry-pick`. **Can any one confirm if below procedure is correct:**

**Step 1:** I have to switch to trunk branch using `git checkout trunk`
**Step 2:** Now merge that commit id using `git cherry-pick MY_COMMIT_ID`
**Step 3:** Now push those changes to trunk using `git push origin trunk`
**Step 4:** Now use `git pull origin trunk` in remote server

Comment: seems ok for me

Answer (score 7):

Yes, cherry-pick is the right solution.

Step 4 sounds like a misunderstanding though. From the client side, all you need to do are steps 1-3, provided that you are on a fresh trunk (otherwise step 3 will fail / git will complain). In order to guarantee that you have a fresh trunk, you can do this:

1. `git checkout trunk`
2. `git pull origin trunk`
3. `git cherry-pick MY_COMMIT_ID`
4. `git push origin trunk`

Comment: it works well. But the commit does not get removed while making pull request